# Problems with # while naming the arguments and drawing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am totally new to macros.

I have the code which I would like to put into a separate command to avoid code duplication

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}  % for  \balance command ON LAST PAGE  (only there!)

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows,matrix,positioning, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/force remake=true}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\NewEnviron{mytikz}[3][]%
  {\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
   \BODY
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
   \end{figure}%
  }


\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\def\mycolor{blue}

% Stackboxes
% http://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/tikz/empilements-de-cubes-sous-tikz

\newcommand{\elemcube}[4][white]
{
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!30, thin] (#2+1,#3,#4) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(0, -1, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!40, thin] (#2,#3+1,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!30, thin] (#2,#3,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle;         
}

\newcommand{\nicebox}[3]{
   \def\latnum{#1}
   \def\lonnum{#2}
   \def\timenum{#3}

   \foreach \time in{\timenum,...,0} {   
      \foreach \lon in{0,...,\lonnum} {
         \elemcube{\latnum}{\lon}{\time}
    }
   }   
}


\begin{mytikz}[x=(90:0.4cm), y=(0:0.4cm), z=(40:0.25cm), axis/.style={->,\mycolor,thick}]{Array example}{fig:ArrayExample}

        \def\latnum{3}
        \def\lonnum{3}
        \def\timenum{6}

        \nicebox{\latnum}{\lonnum}{\timenum}

        \node[\mycolor,anchor=west] at (0,\lonnum+1,0.2) {\tiny $0$};
        \node[\mycolor,anchor=west] at (0,\lonnum+1.8,0.2) {\tiny 1970 Jan 01};

    \end{mytikz}

    \end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I have a lot of errors, including 
`You can't use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode`

Please, help with correct command definition

EDIT: the updated code just hangs during externalization: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape test.tex` 
In my original document it produces erros.
However, it works with `\nicebox{3}{3}{6}`

Comment: You are again showing code that can't be compiled due to the missing \documentclass. And you are not showing where you are adding your command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry again :)

Comment: Nice. It seems like you have a working code. (If repace `\def` by `\edef`.) So how about give us a not-working code so that we can tell why `A` works while `B` does not?